# Matlab - Local Histogram Equalization

Tags: matlab, local, histogram

first of all I'm new at matlab, so if my question is easy sorry for that. And deeply searched on internet but can't find an answer.

I'm trying to do local histogram equalization. I did global histogram equalization by :

> T_histeq=histeq(I);
>
> subplot(2,2,2);imshow(T_histeq);title('Global Histogram Equalization Applied Image');

But for **local** histogram equalization, I couldn't do anything. I know the logic but can't turn it into the code.

Thanks for helps..

Comment: Can you explain your local histogram EQ logic?

Comment: curious about the math too..

Comment: "Apply local histogram equalization to original image with
neighborhood of size 3x3. " This is what I'm trying to do..

Comment: You could consider using BLOCKPROC and HISTEQ in the callback. But wont that lead to block artifacts along the 3x3 neighborhood?